# eso-pic, watermark NOT on title page

Tags: titles, watermark, eso-pic

I use eso-pic package  to put watermark in my document.
It works very well.

But I have a problem with the first page - I would avoid this watermark on first page. 
In describing of eso-pic I am not finding solution for my problem.

```
\usepackage{eso-pic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic
\AddToShipoutPicture{% Add picture to background of every page
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \raisebox{3\baselineskip}{\makebox[\paperwidth]{\begin{minipage}{21cm}\centering
        Draft
     \end{minipage}}}%
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Without a full example document  this is untested but I assume that

```
\AddToShipoutPicture{% Add picture to background of every page
  \ifnum\value{page}>1
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \raisebox{3\baselineskip}{\makebox[\paperwidth]{\begin{minipage}{21cm}\centering
        Draft
     \end{minipage}}}%
  }%
  \fi
}
```

would work.